# live usb not booting after installing windows 8

Tags: boot

I have got a problem while booting ubuntu from live usb. Live USB was working fine before installing windows 8. but after installing windows 8, it doesn't boot with live usb.

what should i do to work live usb again?

Answer (score 0):

Restart your computer, then from the start up options press F12. Now you have the options which one you like to boot first. Choose your USB name and hit enter. I hope this helps. ( Note: There  are different keys for each bios, mind is F12 for example.. Choose which one you like to boot.. I hope this helps